# Get input from label text with Selenium WD as a promise

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm looking to get an input from a labels `for` attribute.

Here's some sample HTML:

`<label for='input_6_36' >Label String</label>
<input name='input_36' id='input_6_36' type='text'>`

The above is dynamically generated so I can't hardcode ID's to fetch my input, hence the reason for approaching it this way.

So here's my custom promise method.

```
wd.addPromiseChainMethod(
    'inputFromLabel',
    function(text) {
        return this
            .elementByXPath("//label[contains(., '" + text + "')]")
            .getAttribute('for', function(val) {
                console.log(val);
            });
    }
);
```

Of which is inplemented like so:

```
it.only('test name', function(done) {
    this.page
        .inputFromLabel('Label String').type('test')
        .nodeify(done);
});
```

So with my custom `inputFromLabel` promise method, I want to return the input from the fetched `for` value.

**I am aware at this moment in time, my custom method will not return the input.**

I need to fetch the input from the value I'm currently logging to the console, but I can't seem to use the given to get an element from it's ID?

Here's a series of step I believe I want to follow:

- Fetch the label from the given text (working)
- Get the `for` attribute from the label (working)
- Get the input from this for value using the ID (not working)
- Return that input to allow for further chaining (in this case, the type() method)

**How can I return the input?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this I think this might work:

```
wd.addPromiseChainMethod(
'inputFromLabel',
function(text) {

    var browser = this;

    return browser
            .elementByXPath("//label[contains(., '" + text + "')]")
            .getAttribute('for')
            .then(function(value) {
                return browser.elementById(value);
            });
});
```